Best practices with pagination
I'm using NodeJS, Express and Dynamoose modeling tool to work with AWS DynamoDB.
Currently, I want to handle data query with pagination of 1.000 users: UserID, UserName, CreatedAt
Basically, I want to call an Express API to fetch all users with 10 users per page, for example:
POST: /users/all
Request body:
{
    "currentPage": 2,
    "itemsPerPage": 10
}

And in my code it should query all user records with Partition Key: "User", and Sort Key: "User Data", sort by CreatedAt descending.
My expectation that the API response returns like this:
{
  "data": [],
  "pageInfo": {
    "currentPage": 2,
    "totalPages": 100,
    "itemsPerPage": 10,
    "totalItems": 1000
  }
}

I understand that AWS DynamoDB returns LastEvaluatedKey but I want the page numbers instead, can you please help?
